# OData query with $expand, but empty root $select

Tags: odata

I've got an OData service with multiple NavigationProperties on a root element. I'd like to perform a query where I don't return any results from the root, e.g. (`$top`'s and metadata removed for brevity)

http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($select=FirstName)&$select=*null*

could return

```
{
    "value": [{
        "Friends": [{
                "FirstName": "Scott"
        }]
    }]
}
```

at present, I'm having to specify at least one column in the root-level `$select`, otherwise **all** the columns at the root level get retrieved

(i.e.
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($select=FirstName)&$select=FirstName
)

Is it possible to somehow specify an empty $select list? I can't see an obvious way in the ABNF.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible but to give me a better idea of the scenario, what are you going to use the data for? Why is that response useful to you if you don't know which person the friends belong to?

Comment: I'm writing a bit of code that generates the OData from a dynamic data source (a user chooses which columns they want to see).

Without a way of specifying an empty $select, I'd need to know at least one 'static' column name at the top level, which just requires more code. Entirely workaround-able, but it just seemed a slight oversight in the odata spec.

Answer (score 9):

ah... found it!

If you have an `$expand` for a NavigationProperty, you can use the NavigationProperty name as the `$select`, so

`http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($select=FirstName)&$select=Friends`

yields*

```
{
    "value": [{
        "Friends": [{
            "FirstName": "Scott"
        }]
    }]
}
```

<sub><sup>* $top and metadata removed for clarity</sup></sub>